# Не сортируется таблица js

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть таблица и я пытаюсь ее отсортировать по столбцам (FirstName),(Age). Не могу найти, в чем ошибка.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const table = document.querySelector('.table');
  const indexToSorting = [...table.tHead.rows[0].cells].findIndex(cell => cell.classList.contains('first'));
  const availableIndexes = [...table.tHead.rows[0].cells].findIndex(cell => cell.classList.contains('second'));
  const sortedRows = [...table.tBodies[0].rows].sort((rowA, rowB) => {

    const cellA = rowA.cells[indexToSorting].innerText;
    const cellB = rowB.cells[indexToSorting].innerText;
    const rowAAvailable = rowA.cells[availableIndexes].innerText;
    const rowBAbailable = rowB.cells[availableIndexes].innerText;
    const nameComparison = cellA.localeCompare(cellB);
    const availableComparison = rowAAvailable.localeCompare(rowBAbailable);
    return nameComparison !== 0 ? nameComparison : availableComparison
  });
 sortedRows.forEach(r => table.tBodies[0].append(r));
});
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="first">FirstName</th>
      <th class="second">Age</th>
      <th>Address</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td>firstname1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>ccdd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>nnnxbxc</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>sdjk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>firstname1</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>firstname1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>ddd</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const table = document.querySelector('.table');
  const indexToSorting = [...table.tHead.rows[0].cells].findIndex(cell => cell.classList.contains('first'));
  const availableIndexes = [...table.tHead.rows[0].cells].findIndex(cell => cell.classList.contains('second'));
  const sortedRows = [...table.tBodies[0].rows].sort((rowA, rowB) => {

    const cellA = rowA.cells[indexToSorting].innerText;
    const cellB = rowB.cells[indexToSorting].innerText;
    const rowAAvailable = +rowA.cells[availableIndexes].innerText;
    const rowBAbailable = +rowB.cells[availableIndexes].innerText;
    const nameComparison = cellA.localeCompare(cellB);
    const availableComparison = rowAAvailable - rowBAbailable;
    return nameComparison !== 0 ? nameComparison : availableComparison
  });
  sortedRows.forEach(r => table.tBodies[0].append(r)); // <---
});
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="first">FirstName</th>
      <th class="second">Age</th>
      <th>Address</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td>firstname1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>ccdd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>nnnxbxc</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>sdjk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>firstname1</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>firstname1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>ddd</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: но ведь оно все еще не сортируется по Age

Comment: Сортируется. Только в виде строк.